# Посчитать суммарное количество строк в файлах txt, лежащих в каталоге

Tags: bash

Требуется посчитать суммарное количество строк в файлах `txt`, лежащих в каталоге, имя которого задано параметром сценария.

```
#! /bin/bash
A1=cat/A1 | grep '\.txt$'| wc -l
echo $A1
```

Что сделать, чтоб оно заработало?

Comment: cat \*.txt | wc -l

Если хотите сохранить в переменной, то

   a1=`cat *.txt | wc -l` ; echo $a1

Comment: @avp пропустили немного `cat $1/*.txt | wc -l`

А можно и иначе

     #!/bin/sh
     cat $1/*.txt | sed -ne '$='

Comment: @alexlz, тоже правильно, но тогда уж добавлю

    cat ${1:-./}/*.txt | wc -l

Comment: @avp по условиям задачи первый параметр должен быть.

Comment: И в самом деле, сам вопрос-то я толком не прочитал.

Тогда проверим количество аргументов

    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo Invalid arguments && exit 1
    fi
    cat $1/*.txt | wc -l

@alexlz, прямо небольшой учебник shell-а для @ника мы с Вами изобразили.

Answer (score 6):

> `#! /bin/bash`

если уж используете [shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29), то его синтаксис не предусматривает пробелов в этом месте.

а скрипт может выглядеть примерно так:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1/*.txt | wc -l
```

или, если требуется сохранить (и потом напечатать) количество строк в переменной:

```
#!/bin/bash
k=$(cat $1/*.txt | wc -l)
echo $k
```

Comment: это неверно, дело не в пробеле после `!`. Фраза *"Blanks after ! are OK"* даже присутствует в [английской версии статьи с  Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), на которую вы сослались (цитата от Dennis Ritchie -- человек, который добавил shebang в Unix). [Is space allowed between `#!` and `/bin/bash` in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/1321) И на современных системах пробелы разрешаются.

Answer (score 0):

Заче через конвейер то сразу, напрямую можно:

```
~$ wc -l ./*
3 ./abc.txt
0 ./big-file
1 ./test1
4 total
```