# Импортировать python в bash

Tags: python, bash, sh

Пробую вызвать скрипт Python из bash в Ubuntu 16. Хочу чтобы из питона напечаталось слово "start".

bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
set -e
set -u
dir=`"/home/myname/foo.py"`
echo directory = $dir
```

питон

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
st = "start"
print(st)
class Moo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        return "string from FOO.py"
```

терминал

```
myname@ubuntu:~$ ./new_bash.sh
hello world
/home/myname/foo.py: строка 3: st: команда не найдена
/home/myname/foo.py: строка 4: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы `st'
/home/myname/foo.py: строка 4: `print(st)'
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как обычно, [присутствует пробел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500217/178576) в [shebang-е](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29), который синтаксисом не предусмотрен.

потому для интерпетации файла используется не программа `/usr/bin/python3`, а текущая оболочка.

Comment: в вопросе пробел  между `#`  и `!` (что действительно не поддерживается: Exec format error), но пробел *после* `!` с самого начала разрешался. По вашей ссылке, оставил [подробнее комментарий](https://goo.gl/6L446W)